# Show discount related to product

Tags: expresso-store, discounts

I'm creating discounts in Expresso Store that use the "match entries field".

Is it possible to show the offer details on the single product view. Most likely from within a product tag?

It would be nice to be able to advertise the discount & offer. Such as buy 5 of these products, get 10% off.

Answer (score 1):

Not automatically. You could just set these as a global variable either as a snippet or using something like [Low Variables](http://gotolow.com/addons/low-variables) and then pull these into the corresponding products pages. This way you only have to update in one place and it updates site wide. It wont be directly linked to the offers from a fully automated point of view but will probably be the easiest way to go about it.

Alternatively you could always run a custom query in your Product page using the [Query Module](http://ellislab.com/expressionengine/user-guide/add-ons/query/) where you retrieve the products that match that discount and if that matches the Entry ID for the product currently being viewed then pull out the Discount and the Notes fields and display that on the page. That would provide a more automated solution but would require a little bit of SQL if you're comfortable with that.